# R quantmod: Timezone in xts object

Tags: r, quantmod, yahoo-finance

I am using getSymbols function from [quantmod](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/quantmod.pdf) library in R to download data from [yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/2975.T/history?p=2975.T). Could anyone explain to me why the time zone of the returned xts data is UTC while yahoo page is showing JST? Please see code below and the highlighted part in the image.

```
> library(quantmod)
> dat=getSymbols("2975.T", adjust=F,auto.assign = FALSE,from="1900-01-01")
> tzone(dat)
[1] "UTC"
```

[image]

Comment: Should not matter as `class(index(data))` is `Date` which has not TZ attribute.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, a `Date` doesn't have a timezone, but you could use `lubridate`, which sets timezone for a `Date` to `UTC` :

```
lubridate::tz(Sys.Date())
[1] "UTC"
```

You could then use `with_tz` to convert back to `JST`:

```
lubridate::with_tz(index(dat),"Japan")
  [1] "2019-06-03 09:00:00 JST" "2019-06-04 09:00:00 JST" "2019-06-05 09:00:00 JST" "2019-06-06 09:00:00 JST"
...
```